# Is it possible to pass a variable as a structure member?

Tags: c, struct

If i have a struct like this:

```
    /* Defined structure with 3 integer as members */
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
struct Myscruct{
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    Mystruct example;   // declared "example" with type "Mystuct"
    example.x=1;        // member 1 have value 1
    example.y=2;        // member 2 have value 2
    example.z=3;        // member 3 have value 3
    char c;
    printf("\nchoose witch member you want to print [ x, y or z]");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    printf("%d", example.c); // this is the part i don't know is possible.
    return 0;
}
```

It is possible to pass a different member to the last printf instead of use a combination of if for example?
If so, what's the syntax of it?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: It's not possible and doesn't make sense either. What is the *problem* you try to solve with this?

Comment: If I have for example a function that do different things based on wich struct member I'm using, will be usefull to create just one function that pass wich member I want to use instead of create X function (or put X if on it) based on number of members of the structure.

Comment: John Bollinger did solve it with the switch case.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use runtime data to reference symbols from your source code.  You can accomplish the apparent aim of your *particular* code with a bit more effort, though:

```
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
struct Myscruct{
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    Mystruct example;   // declared "example" with type "Mystuct"
    example.x=1;        // member 1 have value 1
    example.y=2;        // member 2 have value 2
    example.z=3;        // member 3 have value 3
    char c;
    int xyz;

    printf("\nchoose witch membeer you want to print [ x, y or z]");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    switch (c) {
        case 'x':
            xyz = example.x;
            break;
        case 'y':
            xyz = example.y;
            break;
        case 'z':
            xyz = example.z;
            break;
        default:
            puts("Oops\n");
            return 1;
    }
    printf("%d", xyz);
    return 0;
}
```

There are other alternatives, too, but none so direct as what you were attempting.

Comment: The example in my question was general, i wanted to make it as simple as possible.
Your solution seems simple and clean (but evidently difficult for me as I don't have think about it)
I think it will re solve my "real world" problema too.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called *reflection* and C doesn't have it.

One solution would be to make `Mystruct` contain an *array* instead:

```
struct Mystruct {
    int coordinates[3];
};

...
Mystruct example;
example.coordinates[0]=1;      
example.coordinates[1]=2;  
example.coordinates[2]=3;  
int i;
```

Then ask the user for a number, store it in `i` and use it as an index to the array:

```
printf("%d", example.coordinates[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetof`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
struct MyStruct{
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    size_t addr[] = {
        offsetof(MyStruct, x),
        offsetof(MyStruct, y),
        offsetof(MyStruct, z),
    };
    MyStruct example;   // declared "example" with type "Mystuct"
    example.x=1;        // member 1 have value 1
    example.y=2;        // member 2 have value 2
    example.z=3;        // member 3 have value 3
    char c;
    printf("\nchoose witch membeer you want to print [ x, y or z]");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)((char *)(&example) + addr[c - 'x']));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
choose witch membeer you want to print [ x, y or z]y
2
```